# Search and copy text from Source page

Tags: javascript, html, phantomjs

I wondering how is it possible to search and copy Code from webpage source using javascript.

For example :

```
<td>Valid date: </td>
<td style="padding-right: 10px;">11/2013</td>
```

so I need to grap the text "11/2013" as I am making an automated tool using phantomJS to automate work for me. I almost finished the script in connecting to Webpage and accessing webpages I need. so now how to Search and Grap info and then assign them to array.

P.S. I already have Full webpage source assigned to a variable

Comment: maybe a google search about what you want to do will bring more answers then what you'll get here. it is such a basic question.

Comment: I already googled it, I couldnt find an answer thats why I am askign here